# How do I test for non-null in Ruby::Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm looking to do something like

```
User.select(...).where(:name != nil)
```

without writing something like

```
User.select(...).to_a.find_all {|user| user.name}
```

I can select for null values, but not for non-null.
Is there a trick, or outside Sequel's domain?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `exclude` instead of `where`.

```
User.select(...).exclude(name: nil)
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer you seek is `.where(Sequel.~(name: nil))`

Read more here: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/sql.rdoc

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
User.select(...).where('name IS NOT NULL')
```

Comment: This won't work outside of ActiveRecord. However, `.where('name IS NOT NULL'.lit)` would.